# link_to_remote no Rails 5

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails

Estou partindo para o Rails 5 e não estou conseguindo achar um substituo para o `link_to_remote` que foi descontinuado.

No meu código antigo, eu tenho um link "Cadastro", que ao ser clicado, faz uma requisição ao action "register" e renderiza o retorno na div acima "form".

Segue os elementos básicos da minha view:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>

<div id="form">
</div>

<%= link_to_remote "Cadastro", :update => "form", 
      :url => { :action => "register" } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

No rails 5, para realizar uma requisição AJAX, deve-se usar o **remote: true**

O resultado de acordo com o seu código fica mais ou menos assim:

```
<%= link_to "Cadastro", action: "register", remote: true %>
```

De acordo com a documentação do rails 5:

[image: Documentação rails 5 sobre requisição ajax]

Caso deseje mais informações: [link da documentação do helper 'link_to'](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.4/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)